# Where can I get restful_lib module in Python 2.7 and how to install this module

Tags: python, http, rest

I'm learning Python and trying to test some rest web_service applications. From the below code what I'm trying to do is to post something and to get the result. When I launch this the console gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspaces_branch1\csse120\TestPythonProject\src\UTF-Rest-Client.py", line 9, in <module>
    import restful_lib
ImportError: No module named restful_lib
```

I think it's because I don't have this restful_lib module. where can I get it and how can I install it?
also, I want to know if the launch is good how can I get the returned data?

```
import argparse

#additional lib, need installation (see README)
import restful_lib

testQueueId = 0

# FUNCTIONS

#generate POST content

def postContent():

        xmlData = "<testQueueRequestByNewnancy>"+ \
        "<nancy>"+ \
        "<nancyTargetId>" + args.nancyTargetID + "</nancyTargetId>"+ \
        "<nancyUrl>" + args.nancyUrl + "</nancyUrl>"+ \
        "<nancyVersion>" + args.nancyVersion + "</nancyVersion>"+ \
        "<projectId>" + args.projectID + "</projectId>"+ \
        "<MumID>" + args.MumID + "</MumID>"+ \
        "</nancy>"+ \
            "<user>"+ \
                "<id>" + args.userID + "</id>"+ \
             "</user>"+ \
         "</testQueueRequestByNewnancy>"   

        printVerbose('xmlData =' + xmlData)
        return xmlData

#this function will print text only if verbose is on

def printVerbose(text):
    if args.verbose:
        print(text)


#this function will instruct scheduler through REST API call to do new tests

def callRestApi(content):
    printVerbose('calling REST scheduler API...')

    #recreate complete URL
    base_url = 'http://localhost:8080/test'
    #ensure http:// is at the beginning
    if (base_url[0:7].lower() != 'http://'):
        base_url = 'http://' + base_url
        printVerbose('url is ' + base_url)
        conn = restful_lib.Connection(base_url, username=args.login, password=args.password)
        headers = {'content-type':'text/json', 'accept':'text/json'}
        conn.request_post("/bynewnancy", args={'q': 'Test'}, headers=headers)
        #conn.request_get("/bynewnancy", args=content, returns=conn.ret, headers={'Accept': 'text/json'})

# MAIN

#definition des variables
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #parse command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-v', dest='verbose', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-bt', '--nancyTargetID', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-bu', '--nancyUrl', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-bv', '--nancyVersion', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--projectID', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--MumID', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--userID', required=True)
    #parser.add_argument('-url', '--httpURL', default='127.0.0.1')
    #parser.add_argument('-port', '--httpPort', default='8080')
    #parser.add_argument('-login', '--login', default='admin')
    #parser.add_argument('-pwd', '--password', default='admin')
    #parser.add_argument('-o', '--outputDir', default='.')

    #args is considered as a global variable
    args = parser.parse_args()


    postContent = postContent()
    callRestApi(postContent)

    print('----==============================---- ')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `restful_lib` comes from http://code.google.com/p/python-rest-client, but its last change is 4 years ago, so I wouldn't suggest using this package.

I would strongly recommend the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) library for such a task. A POST request with XML data would simply look like this:

```
requests.post(url, data=my_xml_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, there is a line, "#additional lib, need installation (see README)". I think you'd better see the README file and figure out how to install the "additional lib".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use urllib and urllib2 from Python standard library for making requests and if you will want encode or decode received or sent you should use appropriate encoder or decoder or parser (eg, lxml, BeautifulSoup, json, simplejson, etc ) depending  on a data format and your preference. For getting started I think [how to fetch internet resources](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html) from python documentation may help. Also you can check out urllib and urllib2 more detailed documentation from Python standard library documentation.